# How do you unlock the non-prototype Stealth Camouflage?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

In Metal Gear Solid V: The Phantom Pain,

> I have unlocked the prototype Stealth Camouflage that has a limited time. According to the MGS Wiki for Stealth Camouflage, I must finish Huey Emmerich's ending. I got Quiet's ending and the Truth ending, but is there still a way to get the non-prototype camouflage and how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to complete the Yellow Side Ops to retrieve the AI Pod.

After completing both this and mission 43 (Shining Lights), you should be able to trigger Huey's ending.

Go ahead and complete random side-ops -- eventually Miller should interrupt you and tell you to get back to base, where Huey's final scene will play out.

Comment: Do they ever explicitly refer to the AI Pod in MGSV as the Mammal Pod? I can't recall it being referenced that way. This might confuse people who haven't played Peace Walker.

Comment: I have completed those missions and have done 150/157 side ops (I hate those "Training" ones). Do I have to use R & D or something?

Comment: @CamouflagedCow There are some side ops that you can do multiple times, even after completing them the first time. Go do one or two random side ops in Afghanistan and see if they pop up.

Comment: @SableDreamer I beat the game and then I did like 50 of them.

Comment: @CamouflagedCow Have you listened to all of the yellow casette tracks?

Comment: @SableDreamer Yeah, and got the Truth ending. Also, that isn't needed because I forgot to listen to a few but still got the Truth mission.

Comment: @CamouflagedCow Then I'm stumped -- I am not sure what would have triggered it. I was under the impression that you needed to view Huey's ending to unlock mission 46. If you check your key items, do you already have the "Emmerich's Research Notes" key item?

Comment: ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUPXP.jpg) ........PROOF.................